# Using Ajax to require different php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to use jquery ajax to change the content of my div elemnt by requiring different php files.

here is the ajax code :

```
  $.ajax({
         url:"/project/Functions/project_functions.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{
            functions:num
         },
         success:function(result){
            $("#right_bot").html(result);
         }
      });
```

the project_functions.php would be something like :

```
 $result = '<?php require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php" ?>';
 echo $result;
```

I can see the value being outputted , but the html comment out the php part

```
 <!--?php require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php" ?-->
```

It just comments out the php. Is there a way i load different php files into my div ?

In the **main.php**  file , It has php code , html code , and some style tags. Can I use ajax to load all this into the div element ?  or I have to echo all my html code ?

Comment: When checking the Networks tab in the web inspector, what is being returned when you request `/project/Functions/project_functions.php`?

Comment: i use the dendule to see the generated code. in the #right_bot div , it comment out /project/Functions/project_functions.php?

Comment: ditch the variable assignment and echo, simply have `<?php require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php" ?>` thats all

Comment: it still comment out the code

Comment: Wait, do you actually want to display the raw php code, eg show php tags etc in your div, or do you want to show the ouput of the code, eg html

Comment: i want to load different php files into the div, after i clicked the corresponding location.  It should act like just requiring a php file when first load the page, just i want to make it dynamically, switch different file depends on my click

Comment: You did notice my post having `The solution in your case`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this like that. What you want is that all PHP is excecuted on the server and only the result has to be returned.

You can't send php-code back to javascript and try to run it there, PHP is a serverside language, it will only work on the server. Javascript is clientside, it will only run in the browser.
If you where to send `<?php echo 123; ?>` back to Javascript, you'll get *exactly that* as result, not 123.

The solution in your case is to make **project_functions.php** really require it. This will include the main.php, all it's functions and output.

```
require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php";
```

Some suggested reading: 
http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/

---

A trick which might help you: Paste the link to your urlbar, and add the variables to it. The result you get in your screen is what Javascript will output. Note: This only works for method=get, not post.

In this case browse to `/project/Functions/project_functions.php` and do the simple require per my code above. That output will be send to Javascript.

Comment: if i do  require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php"; in the **project_functions.php**. how do i make everything inside **main.php** go into my div

Answer (score 0):

Send a parameter in the ajax request 8for example type):

```
$.ajax({
         url:"/project/Functions/project_functions.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{
            functions:num, type: "main"
         },
         success:function(result){
            $("#right_bot").html(result);
         }
      });
```

And then in php-file get the type variable:

```
       if($type == "main") {
          require "Panels/Project/Main/main.php"
       }
       else {
           require "Panels/Project/Main/sthelse.php"
       }
```

You should also have some sort of same function name or something to output the results of the file;

```
<?php 
      function printResult() { }


      echo printResult();
```

Comment: But this won't fix the actual problem?

Comment: i have html code and php code in **main.php** and i want to copy them all into my div. Is this possible or its a bad design

Comment: bad, very bad, he he! How does the code look like in main.php? What does it do? Actually this is a simple problem. It's only a if-statement.

Comment: The contents of main.php don't matter in this current case. The main never gets included the proper way, that's the prblem atm :)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp - you should call the require for including the contents of the file, but outputting anything from that file needs an echo or a print statement.

Comment: I know, but again, thats not the problem here. The problem is the understanding of the principle why the returned phpcode wont excecute.

Comment: That depends all together how the code is written and if it's called and if it result of the code is outputted to screen.

Comment: hm...maybe this way is easier to explain it :  all i want is put a php code into the div  => <?php require "xxx.php" ?>

Comment: Actually try to go the file directly with the browser and see what you get! sth like this I think: localhost/mysite/Panels/Project/Main/main.php

Answer (score -2):

Try:

$result = file_get_contents('Panels/Project/Main/main.php');